# Place arrays one next to the other with caption and shape value

Tags: captions, amsmath, arrays

I have the following code snippet executed on Overleaf,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{test}
\author{spanos.nikolaos }
\date{July 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\[
\begin{bmatrix} 
  [1, & 2, & 3]\\
  [4, & 5, & 6]\\
  [7, & 8, & 9]\\
  [10, & 11, & 12]\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\operatorname{shape}(4\times3)
$$\,\to\,$$ %display them in the same row (matrix -> 3 arrays)
[5.5, 6.5, 7.5],%shape(3,) and caption{A},
[1, 2, 3], %shape(3,) and caption{B}
[10, 11, 12] %shape(3,) and caption{C}
\]
\end{document}
```

Following my comments I would like to place everything from the right side of the arrow on the same row with the left side of the arrow along with a shape feature and a caption like array A, B, C below its relative array.

My current output
[image]

Comment: your document produces `! Missing $ inserted.`  after _any_ error do not even look at the pdf except possibly for debugging, if you scroll past an error tex makes no attempt t make sensible pdf output.

Comment: you can not have a `\\ ` newline in`\[` ise an amsmath alignment as in teh answer to your last question. never use `$$` in latex.

Comment: Remove `$$\,`and `\,$$`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand  the requested layout but perhaps something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{test}
\author{spanos.nikolaos }
\date{July 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\begin{bmatrix} 
  [1, & 2, & 3]\\
  [4, & 5, & 6]\\
  [7, & 8, & 9]\\
  [10, & 11, & 12]\\
\end{bmatrix}
&\to 
&[5.5, 6.5, 7.5],
&[1, 2, 3],
&[10, 11, 12] 
\\
\operatorname{shape}(4\times3)
&&
\operatorname{shape}(3,)
&
\operatorname{shape}(3,)
&
\operatorname{shape}(3,)
\\
\text{A}&
&\text{B}&\text{C}&\text{D}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For a reason, it gets out on the right margin of the page. Otherwise, it fits perfectly with what I wanted to have.

Comment: @NikSp the answer as posted is within the page, if your actual document has a smaller page then the layout might need adjusting, you could edit your question to represent your real page size.

Comment: Yeah actually it's strange because I posted it in a new blank document. Ohh w8 I think I found the error.

Comment: @NikSp your document can not be as I posted here but if you show no code impossible to guess what you have changed.

Comment: Yeah I made a change..You have written the first caption as A and I replaced it with a much longer sentence so the whole text was dragged out of the right margin. I have a work around :)